# SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF on closing </script>

Tags: javascript, jquery, eof

Tryn to add dynamically this code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tagcodehead = "function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','{{ code }}');";

    var tagcodebody = "<noscript><iframe src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MN88H8'height='0'' width='0'' style='display:none;visibility:hidden'></iframe></noscript>";

    $(head).add("<script>" + tagcodehead + "</script>");
    $(head).prepend(tagcodebody);
})
```

browser gives me: SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF

Here is the problem - closing script tag

```
$(head).add("<script>" + tagcodehead + "</script>");
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: `height='0'' width='0''` wrong quotes? Fix all the wrong quotes in the strings!

Comment: As an aside, if JavaScript is disabled, how exactly do you expect the `<noscript>` element to be added?

Comment: Why can't you just execute the JS code? Adding it dynamically to a separate script tag just makes it unnecessarily convoluted.

Comment: sabithpocker: thanks, but this is not my problem. (fixed)
phylogenesis: this is a part of tag manager script.

Comment: JJ, I cannot do it. this is a plugin.

Comment: Why would that make any difference?

Comment: User will add only a component that will exicute this script. I dont want him to add more code.

Comment: No, I mean you can do `$(document).ready(function(){   function(w,d,s,l,i){...` which would do exactly the same thing but without the rube goldberg setup.

Comment: @aleXela It being part of a tag manager script doesn't change the fact that if you are running JavaScript, you will, by definition, not be running a `<noscript>` section since that requires you to have JS disabled. You're using JavaScript to add a feature that is only accessible if you don't have JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 5):

You can't embed text with `</script>` inside a script. Even if that "tag" is inside a string, it still terminates the script block for the browser. YOu'll have to break it up:

```
$(head).add("<script>" + tagcodehead + "</scr" + "ipt>");
```

Remember - the browser gets first crack at the raw text of the page/code, and it DOESN'T directly understand what Javascript is. It only understands HTML, which means that the script block terminates at the first instance of `</script>` inside the block, regardless of how/where that closing tags appears within the code inside the block.

Comment: be sure to mark this answer as correct if it helped you @aleXela